# Getting an undefined variable error for my total variable when trying to do a real-time calculation on my form

Tags: javascript, forms, real-time

I was wondering if any of you can help since I am currently learning more about JavaScript. I am trying to do real-time calculations on my form, so when a user clicks on one company, the total will be displayed just for that company. If user clicks on the two companies, the total will be the two companies combined.

I am able to trigger an event when clicking on the radio button, but I am getting that my total variable is undefined. However, if you see in the JS portion of my Codepen, I do have it defined under the calculateTotal function. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/tacoholic/pen/RwWxbjj?editors=1011

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <h1>ABC Corp</h1>
            <h4>Bill for the month of: June</h4>
            <h4>Payment due: 5/10/2020</h4>
            <hr />
            <form  action="" id="montlhybillform" onsubmit="return false">
                <table id="billing">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">Company</th>
                        <th width="25%">Pizzas</th>
                        <th width="25%">Orders</th>
                        <th width="25%">Price/pizza</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ACME</td>
                        <td>Cheese</td>
                        <td>10,000</td>
                        <td>$0.039</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio1">
                                <input type="radio" id="acmeradio"name="selectedbill" value="Acmemonthly" onclick="calculateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">390.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NB Distribution</td>
                        <td>Sausage</td>
                        <td>1,000</td>
                        <td>$0.049</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="radio1" id="radio2">
                                <input type="radio" id="nbradio"name="selectedbill" value="Nbmonthly" onclick="calculateTotal()">
                                <label for="regular">49.00</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
            <hr>
        </div>
</div>



  Javascript

    var total_bill =  new Array();
        total_bill["AcmeMonthly"] = 390.00;
        total_bill["NbMonthly"] = 49.00;

    function getMonthlyTotal() {
            var monthlyRadio = document.getElementsByName('selectedbill');
            for (i = 0; i < monthlyRadio.length; i++) {
                if (monthlyRadio[i].checked) {
                    user_input = monthlyRadio[i].value;
                }
            }
            return total_bill[user_input];
        }

          function calculateTotal() {
            var total = getMonthlyTotal();
            var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
            document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Your Total is: $" + total;
            total.style.display = 'block';
        }

        function hideTotal() {
        var total = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
            total.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array will have only number as index.
For your use case it should be object.

```
var total_bill =  {};
total_bill["AcmeMonthly"] = 390.00;
total_bill["NbMonthly"] = 49.00;
```

And value in input checkbox must match these keys in object

```
<input type="radio" id="acmeradio"name="selectedbill" value="AcmeMonthly" onclick="calculateTotal()">
<input type="radio" id="nbradio"name="selectedbill" value="NbMonthly" onclick="calculateTotal()">
```

or you can try the reverse

```
    var total_bill =  [];
    total_bill[0] = 390.00;
    total_bill[1] = 49.00;

     <input type="radio" id="acmeradio"name="selectedbill" value=0 onclick="calculateTotal()">
     <input type="radio" id="nbradio"name="selectedbill" value=1 onclick="calculateTotal()">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here. For starters, the value of the first radio button is set in your html to `Acmemonthly`, not the numerical value you want it to represent.

You're looking by numerical index but storing by named property. `total_bill["AcmeMonthly"] === 390.00;` but `total_bill[0] === undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It returns undefined because the radio button value is set to `Acmemonthly` while the object property is `AcmeMonthly` (same for the second one). Changing this works (i've checked it). However, I strongly advise you not to work this way.